# MySQL mutual condition query with single table

Tags: mysql, database, join

I am receiving user_id 1 and 2 from post. I want to get hospital id sharing by both user like 4.

user_hopitals table

```
 id | user_id | hospital_id
 1  |   1     |    4
 2  |   2     |    4
 3  |   1     |    5
 4  |   2     |    9
```

hospitals table

```
id | name 
4  | abc hospital
5  | XYZ hospital
9  | def hospital
```

I want the data like

```
 hospital_id | hospital_name
     4       | abc hospital
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SELF JOIN`, e.g.:

```
SELECT h.id. h.name
FROM user_hospitals uh1 JOIN user_hospitals uh2 ON uh1.hospital_id = uh2.hospital_id
JOIN hospitals h ON uh1.hospital_id = h.id
WHERE uh1.user_id = 1 AND uh2.user_id = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is aggregating and a `having` clause:

```
select uh.hospital_id, uh.name
from user_hospitals uh join
     hospitals h
     on uh.hopital_id = h.id
where uh.user_id in (1, 2)
group by uh.hospital_id, uh.name
having count(distinct uh.user_id) = 2;
```